# Overriding appendChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  trying to override `appendChild` method so that I can have control over dynamically  created elements and modify them if needed before inserting into the page. I tried with this example code, just to see if it could be done:

```
var f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function(){f.apply(this, arguments); };
```

and it works for simple examples.However, when I try to load jquery after this code:

```
<script> 
    var f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
    Element.prototype.appendChild = function(){f.apply(this, arguments); };
</script>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I get this errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined jquery.min.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

So, why it doesn't work with jquery ? Is there a safe way to override appendChild ?

Comment: Overriding any core function is a very, VERY bad idea. Instead, write your own `function appendChild(parent,child)` function in a scope or namespace you control.

Comment: just wrap the function instead overwriting it. this is a bad ideia in the entire universe.

Comment: Why exactly would you change a native method like this, I really can't see how you would gain any more control over dynamic elements by doing so, and it's very bad pratice? As for the jQuery error, it looks more like something else went wrong, and you're getting `undefined`  instead of the element, not that the `appendChild` method itself is faulty.

Comment: "*Why it doesn't work with jQuery?*" - because jQuery expects it to behave properly and return the appended DOM node; whereas your version returns [`undefined`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ofngyy4v/). I have no problems extending prototypes, but I really would echo the others, ahead of me, and strongly advise you to not change standard/native functionality of existing (otherwise-predictable) methods.

Comment: wow David, I was just missing return statement, thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing the lesson there, to be honest.

Comment: I understand you completely, but you don't understand the context in which this script is supposed to be used.

Comment: When overwriting natives is the solution, you didn't define the problem correctly. This smells of a bigger problem

Comment: I guess OP is looking for kind of mutation observer workaround

Answer (score 2):

It is ill advised to overwrite native functions, but if you do it than make sure you return the appended element as well to prevent problems with code that uses the returned value of the native "appendChild" function:

```
window.callbackFunc = function(elem, args) {
  // write some logic here
}
window.f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function() {
    window.callbackFunc.call(this, arguments);
    return window.f.apply(this, arguments);
};
```